# implement two level lock

Tags: c++, locking

I have writeen a dll to store some info in memroy, there are many threads want
to visit the data at the same time, so I use a read/write lock to sync. And I export
some function to the user, in the function, I require the lock, then get data, then exit
and release the lock. For example, like this function.

```
void GetData(data)
{
    //require lock

    //get data

    //release lock
}
```

my users may call GetData many times at there function, for example,

```
void ProcessData()
{
    // do something 1

    GetData(data1);

    // do something 2

    GetData(data2);

    ...
}
```

at the same time, other thread may change the data in my dll by call other export function of my dll,so data may change between GetData(data); and GetData(data2); but my user want my data never change at ProcessData because of data1 may releated to data2 in this situation.
And I don't want to expose my lock in my dll.
Is there a way to implement something like this, Thx!

Comment: Please tag your question with the appropriate language...

Comment: It seems like you've figured out what you need to do, you just need to familiarize yourself with the right library interface.  The best answer may depend on your platform.  Do a search for `pthread_rwlock_init` or `InitializeSRWLock` as some possible examples.  Boost or C++11 might also help; not sure what they provide...  Also, you might want to consider a simple mutex rather than a rwlock, depending on your needs.

Comment: You found out that the only one that reliably lock is the *client* code.  Usually least capable of getting it right, this is what makes threading hard.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want people to be able to write data while ProcessData is running?  Or should people who write be blocked until ProcessData is done?

If yes, then you can export 2 functions that will let ProcessData lock out any writers.

```
LockOutWriters() { // lock }
WriteData() { // blocks if above is locked }
UnLockWriters() { // unlock }
```

If no, then you'll need to take a snapshot of the data at the time GetData() is called and make sure that whenever ProcessData calls GetData, it pulls data from that snapshot.